# is it written in flex? the steam client application

Tags: firefox, steam

I was about to download the PC Game Mafia II ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_II ). The site said that do i have steam and i said no ... it asked whether to download and i gave yes.

After downloading a 1.5mb exe it executed, dowloaded and installed additional files. After that the program opened. It gave me a feeling that that could have written in flex. if some body could clear this then that could be nice...

besides, i went to the mafia ii official site to download the demo and again it asked whether i have steam installed and i said yes. then the firefox application launch dialog box appeared. and again i had this question how to launch an application using firefox... ??
may be i should ask this as a separate question but since it is associated with the above question i asked it here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam is written in C++, using (among other things) WebKit and MFC (at least on Windows). The installers are written by the software authors themselves -- they can be written in anything, many use DemoShield or Windows Installer. Downloading directly from Steam uses installation scripts bundled, though, not a separate installer.

If you are talking about the Steam client, it's primarily C++. If you are talking about the installers, it could be anything. If you're talking about the "install to Steam" integrated installer, that's also C++.